# Как ограничить знаки после точки в результате выполнения avg? в BigQuery(sql workspase)

Tags: bigquery

```
select 
  date,
  avg(revenue) as average_amount_of_orders 
  
from `testTable`
group by date
```

И вот что мне выдает в ответе:

[image: вот что мне выдает в ответе]

Мне же нужно что бы в "*average_amount_of_orders*" было не больше 2-х знаков после запятой. Я честно искал как это сделать в интернете, однако по прошествии 20 минут я решил что целесообразнее будет задать вопрос.

Comment: вы поставили метку [tag:sql], но вам же явно не нужен ответ про ansi sql, вам нужен ответ про какую-то конкретную реализацию sql-сервера. так укажите её в метках или хотя бы в тексте вопроса, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

Надо вызвать функцию ROUND, первый аргумент - что округлять, второй аргумент - сколько знаков оставить.

```
... ROUND(AVG(...), 2) AS ...
```